# Property 'x' does not exist on type '{toggle():void}'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-edge, nuxt-bridge

I am pretty new to typescript. Now, I have setup nuxt(bridge with typescript) app and created a component named menuIcon as such;

```
  <div class="container">


    <div class="menu-icon" :class="active ? 'change' : ''" @click="toggle">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div
      class="overlay"
      :class="active ? 'overlay-slide-right' : 'overlay-slide-left'"
      @click="toggle"
      id="overlay"
    >
    <!-- html contents here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">


export default {
  data(){
    const active:boolean=false;
    return{
        active
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle():void{
       this.active= !this.active
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
/*css contents here*/
}
</style>
```

It is working in browser but I am seeing the following error in my terminal.

```
TS2339: Property 'active' does not exist on type '{ toggle(): void; }'.
    41 |   methods: {
    42 |     toggle():void{
  > 43 |        this.active= !this.active
       |             ^^^^^^
    44 |     },
    45 |   },
    46 | };

ERROR in components/MenuIcon.vue:43:27
TS2339: Property 'active' does not exist on type '{ toggle(): void; }'.
    41 |   methods: {
    42 |     toggle():void{
  > 43 |        this.active= !this.active
       |                           ^^^^^^
    44 |     },
    45 |   },
    46 | };
```

Apparently it's something about typing but I am not sure how to fix it. I would very much appreciate anyone to shed light on me about the issues. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The component definition needs to be [declared with Vue's `defineComponent` to enable TypeScript support](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components). Nuxt Bridge recommends using `defineComponent` from the `#app` import, although you could also import it from `@vue/composition-api`.  Using the `#app` alias is preferrable because it includes Nuxt specific types from `@nuxtjs/composition-api`.

*Example*:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '#app';
                      
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    const active:boolean = false;
    return {
      active
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(): void {
      this.active = !this.active
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

The `#app` alias is normally setup in `.nuxt/tsconfig.json`, but I found it's necessary to re-declare it in the root app's `tsconfig.json` to work in VS Code:

```json
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      ⋮
      "#app": [
        "node_modules/@nuxt/bridge/dist/runtime/index"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/nuxt-bridge-ts-demo)

Comment: @HungOm I see now. Nuxt Bridge actually exports `defineComponent` from `#app`, but you could also import it from `@vue/composition-api`. Updated answer. Using the `#app` one is preferrable because it will include Nuxt specific types from `@nuxtjs/composition-api`.